# How can I retrieve dropdown selection data from a mySQL database and then calculate the percentage of times that selection was made

Tags: php, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin, dropdownbox

What I need to do is calculate how many times apples was selected from the dropdown and stored and then compare to total entries for a result that is to be echo. So in this case since apples is in the DB 3 times of 20 entries, my result should be 10%.

My html dropdown is as such:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" />
    <input type="hidden" name="formID" value="forms1" />
    <select name="week1selection">
        <option value="0" selected id="0">Week 1 Food Selection</option>
        <option value="apples">Apples</option>
        <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
        <option value="pears">Pears</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

My database(forms1) has a table(demo) that is setup with 2 columns: ID and week1selection.

My PHP that produces a result in the browser of apples as many times as selected is:

```
<?php
    //connect to the server
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

    //connect to the database
    mysql_select_db("forms1");

    //query the database
    $sqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM demo WHERE week1selection = 'apples'");

    //fetch the results and convert them into an array
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery)): {
        $id = $rows['ID'];
        $week1selection = $rows['week1selection'];

        echo "$week1selection<br/>";
    }
    endwhile;
?>
```

The above script produces the following because apples are in the DB 3 times out of the 20 selections and entries that have been made:
apples
apples
apples

What I need to do is calculate how many times apples was selected compared to total entries and echo the result. So in this case since apples is in the DB 3 times of 20 entries, my result should be 10%.

Comment: That'd depend on how/where you're recording which selection was made. As is, none of your code does that.

Comment: I have a process page that records the data:
<?php
 require_once('config.php');

 /*Storing the data into a variable*/
 $value = $_POST['week1selection'];

 /*Cleans the array to protect against injection attacks.*/
 function f_clean($array){
  return array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $array);
 }

 /*Storing the data into the database*/
 $sql = "INSERT INTO demo (week1selection) VALUES ('$value')";

 if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 mysql_close();

?>

Comment: so recording the data is not the issue

Comment: So it seems you should count how many times 'apples' appears, count the total number of entries, and do the math to find a percentage? Am I missing something? I'm not clearly understanding what isn't working for you.